# `*': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

i am trying with some basics.

```
space = " "
puts "Some Text: "
count = gets.chomp.to_i
print "#{count}" * space
print "*"
```

when i trying to run this it shows this error
`*': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Comment: You just have the expression backwards, try `puts space * count`

Comment: @user1875195 thank you, it's working. :)

Comment: @user1875195 You should consider posting this as an answer so that Mani can mark it as accepted and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted something like this

```
space = " "
puts "Some Text: "
count = gets.chomp.to_i
puts space * count
puts "*"
```

and use the form `string * fixnum` to repeat a string `count` times

Comment: @Mani Please consider accepting any answer which solved your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers